# JavaScript pass object into function by another function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Let me preface this as saying this is not the way I wanted to code the functions (inline and hijacks), but I have to work around a third party app config interface, with altering the source code as a final option.

So I have an image that calls an `onclick` function:

```
 <img src="images/button_closed.gif" id="img100023" border="0" 
  onclick="OnNodeImageClick(event, this)" href="theurl.cfm">
```

The function takes the vars event, this and gets the URL:

```
 function OnNodeImageClick(evt, clickedImage) {
    var href = clickedImage.getAttribute("href"); 
  ...
```

I need to do this exact same logic on a separate element that shares the original's id numbers:

```
 <span id="node100023" >External Links</span>
```

What I have tried is this as the html:

```
 <span id="node100023" 
  onclick="javascript:OverwriteToTreeHandler($(this).attr('id'))">
  External Links</span>
```

and this as my function:

```
 function OverwriteToTreeHandler(nodeID){
    var clickedItem = 'img'+nodeID.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');  
        //tried $('body').find( clickedItem ) didnt work 
     OnNodeImageClick(event, clickedItem );
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object img100023 has no method 'getAttribute'

However by statically assigning the identifier in the HTML.

What I have tried is this as the html, I get exactly the result I want:

```
 <span id="node100023" 
  onclick="javascript:OnNodeImageClick(event, img100023)">
  External Links</span>
```

I assume this has to do with the parameters, and the fact when I attempt to dynamically get the element, it is not registering it as an object, but I am not connecting on  how this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnNodeImageClick` is expected a DOM element - you are passing a string. Try this:

```
function OverwriteToTreeHandler(nodeID) {
    var clickedItem = document.getElementById('img'+nodeID.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

    OnNodeImageClick(event, clickedItem);
}
```

Also, `this.id` is preferable (performance and clarity wise) to `$(this).attr('id')` when you call `OverwriteToTreeHandler`.

Comment: worked great, quick followup, why would $('#img'+nodeID.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')); still return the Object error? my understanding is that its the same as document.getElementById('img'+nodeID.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

Comment: @worthycaesar the jQuery function (`$(...)`) gives you a jQuery object with certain methods. `getAttribute()` is not one of them, hence `$(...).getAttribute()` fails. `document.getElementById(...)` returns a DOM element, which does have a `getAttribute()` method.

Comment: ahh , if the function had used jquery .attr() , I wouldve been fine, understood, thanks so much